# activityManager.getRunningServices(int maxNum) in android 8?

Tags: android, deprecated, android-8.0-oreo, android-api-levels

Android documentation says this method is deprecated in android Oreo. How can I get the list of running services in `API-26` then? Is there any workaround?

What about getting a list of running processes? I used `activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()` and again got the same result, while there is no deprecation point in android documentation!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningServices(int)

Comment: As of LOLLIPOP, this method is no longer available to third party applications!

Comment: form `oreo` not `LOLLIPOP`

Comment: Yes, Thanks. So what is the workaround?

Comment: *As of O, this method is no longer available to third party applications* i think there is no workaround above api 26

Comment: google making methods unavailable is a good indication they don't want you doing this. Take the hint

Comment: What about getting a list of running processes? I used it and again got the same result, while there is no deprecation point in android documentation! @NileshRathod

Comment: And by the way, Clean Master still works on android 8! It boosts ram! So how does it work?!

Comment: I am trying to figure this same thing out too. P.S. CleanMaster is a piece of **** that only causes problems for us app developers.